# What would you call someone who needs to watch the news every day?

Tags: single-word-requests

My friend claims there are people who have or are perceived to have some disorder where they must watch the news every day or they feel very agitated. Disregarding the truth of such a claim, what would you call such people? He suggested "newsivore" and I would just say "news obsessed."

Is there a proper term?

Comment: It is a form of OCD.

Comment: You may use "nerd" and "geek".

Comment: Every _day_? Isn't that (or shouldn't that be) a cultural norm? Kids these days, can't even pick up a newspaper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

News junkie. 'Junkie' originally, and by default still, means a heroin addict, but has been applied to addicts to other things.

As an example, here is the phrase used in a BBC interview with an actress in a BBC programme about a news programme:

> ["I am a news junkie, definitely," she admits. "I read the paper pretty
>   much every day, as well as getting news from the internet and on TV.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-14166187)

Comment: Correct. This is an established term, popularized by everyone's favorite Doctor of Journalism, gonzo-wise.